# how to implement gmail client with ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

how would I develop an Email client in Ruby-on-rails taking Gmail as an example? I would be especially interested in the send email functions

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: What exactly about Gmail are you trying to implement? Or do just mean a webmail interface?

Comment: yes, would be interested in a webmail interface that is ruby on rails based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending email with rails is crazy easy check out http://guides.rails.info/action_mailer_basics.html and use GMail to send the emails. I use the fetcher gem to download emails http://github.com/look/fetcher.

I have an open source application that provides an extremely simplistic web-mail interface as one of its features, you can get the source at http://github.com/thinkbohemian/WhySpam. You can see it in action at http://whyspam.me (make an email address, send something to it, then log in...you can see the interface). Good luck let me know if you have more specific questions

Answer (score 2):

To send emails you just need to interface with a SMTP ([wiki](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)) server. Ruby provides this facility inside the `net/smtp` module, check it out [here](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/index.html).

You can actually use **GMail** server to do your tests.